Lightning + MLFlowLogger logging checkpoints, can't register in Model Registry
I am using a Sagemaker-managed MLflow tracking server, and Pytorch LightningCLI --
The tracking server was created with "AutomaticModelRegistration": true, and we're using the MLFlowLogger with log_model set to True as well.
This gave us the impression that our logged models would show up in the model registry. However, not only is that not the case, but we also don't see the "register model" option for the model when we navigate to the model artifact -- does the model have to be in a specific format or are there other pre-requisites before a model is picked up and automatically registered?
Essentially, it's exactly the same problem as listed here: https://lightning.ai/forums/t/mlflow-model-cant-be-registered/4163
But the only answer on that forum post doesn't help (The question is asking why the MLflowLogger isn't logging the model in a register-able format, and the answer is just reiterating documentation on how to log the model, which I am already following).
Has anyone run into this and have any ideas how to properly log and register the model so that it can be picked up by model registry?
